# Long running background process

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

**What i want:** To run a background service that would communicate with our server via RESTFUL webservice after regular interval of 1 minute (Its a strict project requirement. So cannot increase it.)

**What i have:** I tried various approaches using simple **BroadcastReceivers** with a simple **Service** AND **WakefulBroadcastReceivers** using **WakefulIntentService** etc..

**Main Problem:** The main issue is when device screen is ON, everything is working fine on regular/fixed intervals but when the screen goes off OR devices gets locked, then the alarm Manager triggers service with a minimum interval of **5 Minutes**.. Thats exactly what i dont want. I want the same 1 minute interval while device is locked/screen off.

Below is my code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />   
  <receiver android:name=".MyScheduledReceiver" />
  <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
```

**Activity.java**

```
 MyScheduledReceiver.scheduleAlarms(MainActivity.this);
```

**gradle**

```
// Background long running process
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:wakeful:1.0.+'  


repositories {
maven {
    url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
}
```

}

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyScheduledReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


private static final int PERIOD = 60 * 1000;
private static final int INITIAL_DELAY = 2000; // 5 seconds

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

    try {

        if (i.getAction() == null) {
            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, BackgroundService.class);

        } else {
            scheduleAlarms(context);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, MyScheduledReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD, pi);

}
```

}

**BackgroundService**

```
public class BackgroundService extends WakefulIntentService {


public BackgroundService() {
    super("BackgroundService");
}

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {

    sendNotification("HELLOO");

    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    MyScheduledReceiver.scheduleAlarms(BackgroundService.this);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {


    try {
        Intent intent = intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Notification notification;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Currently i am simply showing a notification with a sound in the notification bar from my BackgroundService.
I would really appreciate your help. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

What you want is not supported on Android 6.0 anyway. Android 6.0 will not issue alarms every minute, to any application, thanks to Doze mode.

The closest thing that will work is:

- Have a service that uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` to get control every minute to do your work
- Have that service acquire a `WakeLock` and keep the CPU on all the time
- Have that service use `startForeground()` and `START_STICKY` to minimize the amount of time that it is not around and therefore incapable of doing this work
- Make sure that application is added to the "ignore battery optimizations" whitelist in Settings
- Ignore the cries of anguish from users, complaining that their battery life is atrocious

Comment: Ok Google guy but i tested with your point # 3 also but same results. Also i am testing on 5.0.. Samsung S4.. So i am confused why its not working in older version, if it is deprecated in 6.0 then thats fine i will try with ScheduledExecutorService , But why not currently working in 5.0.. Where i am missing ?

Comment: @NomanHamid: "So i am confused why its not working in older version" -- `AlarmManager` itself was modified in Android 4.4 to ignore polling periods under a minute. However, device manufacturers can and do change things, so you may be experiencing some modifications that Samsung made to save on power, where they raised the lowest polling period to five minutes. Trying to do work every minute is considered an anti-pattern, and everybody from Google on down is trying to prevent it.

Comment: If this is the case, then i will test the same case on Nexus 5 Android 6.0 then.. I hate samsung btw.. But does that mean ScheduledExecutorService  will also gonna get some issues with it if less than 5 mins ?

Comment: @NomanHamid: "But does that mean ScheduledExecutorService will also gonna get some issues with it if less than 5 mins ? " -- no, because that is within your own process. These limits, like the official one-minute minimum, come from `AlarmManager`, `JobScheduler`, and other external timing mechanisms, ones that lie outside of your process.

Comment: It would be useful if sample code could be provided for others using the ScheduledExecutorService example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, MyScheduledReceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,REQUEST_CODE, i, 0);

// We want the alarm to go off 3 seconds from now.
long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
firstTime += 3 * 1000;//start 3 seconds after first register.

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,
        600000, sender);//10min interval

}
```

Comment: Please explain how this will address the question.

Comment: you can set your interval

Comment: actually i got it working with my work using AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP

Comment: @riazhasan  try to make it work after killing your app and device lock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Handler to obtain this goal? `AlarmManager` will typically work on a battery friendly rhythm when possible. Whereas Handlers are much more exact.

For example, you could run this code in your `Service`:

```
// Store this as a member variable
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// This can be a member variable or local
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // Do stuff

      // Tell the Handler to call itself again
      mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
   }
};

// Put this at the start of `Service`
mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
```

As Commonsware points out, having the Handler declared as it is above would cause the Handler to run on the Main Thread. Here is some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) on how to get a Handler to run in the background:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages here
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think even using handlers he will have to keep CPU lock to let service run while screen is off.

Comment: "Timers will typically work on a battery friendly rhythm when possible" -- the OP is not using `Timer`, and `Timer` has no knowledge of the battery. Also, this particular approach to using `Handler` would cause the work to be performed on the main application thread, which is not a good idea for a service.

Comment: Oops, I had meant the AlarmManager. That part is correct though, right? Android fires Alarms off more-or-less at the right time, in order to keep processing to segments of time. As opposed to running when they want, which might keep the device permanently active.